# Avoiding catastrophic cancellation with $\sqrt{1+x} - 1$ for $x$ close to $0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, catastrophic-cancellation

> I'm trying to figure out how to avoid catastrophic cancellation for the following expression
>   $$\sqrt{1+x} - 1$$
>   for $x$ being a number *very* close to $0$.

Of course, the answer would come to $0$ unless the expression is changed around.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You could use $$\sqrt{1+x}-1=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}$$

Answer (score 6):

If you want accurate results without computing any square root, you could use $[n,n]$ Padé approximants.

These could be
$$\sqrt{1+x}-1\sim \frac{2 x}{x+4}$$
$$\sqrt{1+x}-1\sim \frac{4 x (x+2)}{x (x+12)+16}$$

Comment: I'd like to point out that these equivalences are with the limit as $x\to0$, not $x\to\infty$ as you might usually expect from $\sim$.

Comment: @Jam. I totally agree with you. In the question, it is specified *"for $x$ being a number very close to $0$"*.

Answer (score 5):

If $x$ is seriously small, e.g. $\ x < 10^{-14}$, and you don't care too much about terms of order $O(10^{-28})$ then why not use:

$$\sqrt{1+x}\approx1+\frac{x}{2}$$